# Json Web Token (JWT) en Node.js con express

Tags: nodejs, express, jwt, openssl

Estoy trabajando con la librería  [Json Web Token](https://jwt.io/) de Javascript, en donde creo el token con la función:

```
var token = jwt.sign({data: 'foobar', 'secret', { expiresIn: 60 * 60 });
```

Para verificar mi token uso, la función:

```
jwt.verify(token, 'shhhhh')
```

Que es lo que sugiere la librería, pero quiero que en el campo donde recibe el parámetro `secret`, pueda usar algún tipo de certificado. La librería indica que  para realizar generar el  token con el certificado, se haga de la siguiente manera:

```
var cert = fs.readFileSync('private.key');
var token = jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, cert, { algorithm: 'RS256'});
```

Para verificar el token usando el certificado,lee un archivo con extensión `.pem`, de la siguiente manera:

```
var cert = fs.readFileSync('public.pem');  
   jwt.verify(token, cert, function(err, decoded) {
   console.log(decoded.foo) // bar
});
```

Ahora mi pregunta es, ¿cómo genero esos certificados que se solicitan en la sección del token? Esto para que  funcionen con ese certificado.

Answer (score 5):

Bien

Para  generar los certificados de manera local se puede usar  **openssl** , que permite generar los certificados requeridos con  sus respectivas extensiones `.key` o `.pem` a través de la consola, para mi caso en particular me base en [este tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3D1iYOAqvbc) para generar los certificados en windows.

Una vez generados los archivos, se guarda la ubicación del archivo en una variable, usando el modulo `fs` de `javascript`. Entonces quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
var cert = fs.readFileSync('private.pem');
var token = jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, cert, { algorithm: 'RS256'});
```

Ahora para validar el token se hace de la siguiente manera:

```
var cert = fs.readFileSync('private.pem');  
   jwt.verify(token, cert, function(err, decoded) {
   console.log(decoded.foo) // bar
});
```

Entonces  el token se genera y se valida usando los certificados.